# Open source and web based html5 document viewer

Tags: html

Is there a free web based html5 document viewer?

Comment: Are you referring to a web browser?

Comment: No,am looking for something i can build for my server,i.e the flash thingy behind scribd.There is an opensource implemetation of a document viewer but using flash.

Comment: Do you mean, `is there a library for converting proprietary document formats to an open and viewable format that I can use in an HTML5 based website to allow people to access my content without requiring them to use Flash or other similar technologies?` ... if so, you should say `that` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenOffice (or LibreOffice) can be run as a service that let's you stream documents to it and it can return other formats.  PDF and Flash are definitely supported.  I think it can also do HTML.  It's not a full viewer -- just the HTML -- you would have to figure out how you want to display it on a page.

Answer (score 11):

You could take a look at the [DocumentCloud project](http://www.documentcloud.org/opensource) which has a bunch of components including an HTML5 Open Source Document viewer - [NYtimes Document viewer](https://github.com/documentcloud/document-viewer) - hosted on git (Apache license)

Comment: FYI this is also a wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/navis-documentcloud/

Answer (score 6):

Open source PDF HTML5 Viewer from Mozilla:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 3):

Huh... [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/), maybe?

You're a bit vague on the requirements here, but by "document" I assume you mean text documents (.doc(x), .rtf, .txt), presentations or the occasional PDF file. In which case Google Docs does all of that well, and allows you to create files in its own format or upload them in their normal format.

It's not entirely HTML5 (debatable buzzword, really), but it uses some.

EDIT: following your clarification in a comment to your question, you could use Google Docs for that, it has an embedded viewer that you can put insert in web-pages. You'd need to have the files uploaded to a Google Docs account and then view them with that.

- [Embedding Spreadsheets](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244)
- [Embedding Presentations](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86101)
- [Embedding a PDF File](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=5030cc0904ffc188&hl=en) (assuming it would work similarly for documents)

EDIT2: Actually, you can (or at least used to be able to) embed files that are not even hosted on Google Docs, read this 2009 post on the [Embeddable Google Document Viewer](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html).

Comment: Look at this project maybe you will see what i mean.http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

Comment: Does that allow editing as well?

Comment: @Mambro: For docs/spreadsheets, of course. Not for PDFs though. But it integrates with tools that do.

Comment: sorry I mean something different like 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861909/updating-existing-google-docs-via-third-web

Answer (score 2):

Not open source, but it's brand new and the first HTML5 Document viewer - http://crocodoc.com/

Comment: crocodoc is pretty nice, but not a solution for people who deal with private documents.

Comment: As of January 15, 2018, Crocodoc is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Vuzit.  It's free up to a certain point and supports cross-browser rendering with HTML5 http://www.vuzit.com

Answer (score -4):

You could try Mozilla Firefox or Chromium, they are pretty well known and open source.