# Possibility of fully functional word-processor in html5/css3/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

With the current state of html5/css3/javascript and the browsers support of it, do you think it is possible to create a fully functional word-processor (or document editor) like Microsoft Word or LibreOffice Writer with > 80% of its features? I'm talking about the rendering and editing engine, I think a server-side component for loading and saving documents to disk is always required because of security, conversion, etc.

Of course I am not talking about HTML-editors which are commonly available (e.g. CKEditor, TinyMCE, etc.) but I compare it with products like [DevExpress DXRichEdit](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Rich_Editor/), [Telerik RichTextBox](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/controls/richtextbox.aspx) and [TX Text Control](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/dotnetwpf/overview/). Why would you at this moment still need technologies like Silverlight, ActiveX or Flash to create a webbased word-processor?

There are some initiatives regarding [HTML5 document viewers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089970/open-source-and-web-based-html5-document-viewer), but besides Google Docs and Zoho Docs (which are limited in features compared to desktop based word-processors, and operate more like advanced HMTL editors) there is little available in regards to webbased word-processors.

Is there a reason there is no HTML5 word-processor yet? What do you think is still missing from the current technology to be able to create a webbased word-processor suitable as replacement for products like MS Word?

Comment: What's missing from Google Docs document editor that makes you think it's not a word processor? It's been around since before there was a HTML5 and I've been using it instead of MS Word for all my word processing needs.

Comment: I doubt whether a word processor really needs >80% of the features that for example Word has. What do we need about 3,000 features for when writing a text document; my printer cannot print video yet.

Comment: Try Syncfusion [Document Editor](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/document-editor). It uses a custom canvas based render engine for proper WYSIWYG editing experience and features similar to MS Word.

Comment: MS Word (especially creating/applying styles) troubles me so much that I might just create one myself. I'd like to be fully in control of styles. I wish there was a way to use CSS inside Word (or any other editor).

Answer (score 0):

No if you think anything more advanced than a letter to your aunt.

HTML WYSIWYG components are horrible mess (contentEditable). You might almost success for one browser, but xplatform stuff (IE) just wont fly.

Google Docs is the best what money can buy today and it is flakey at the best.

However Silverlight or Adobe do not offer anything better.

The best bet is to hope that HTML5 APIs got to the point pure Javascript editor is possible. But they are not yet there.

Comment: I beg to differ. There are already good source-code editors with syntax highlighting, so surely a word processor is feasible. If you're targeting HTML5, there's no saying you need to rely on contentEditable at all - these new source-code editors don't, they implement a custom cursor and document operations. Or you could go even lower and start with canvas, which would be more work, but perhaps could achieve better performance. Bottom line is there are plenty of ways you could do this...

Comment: Mozilla tried Bespin with <canvas> and dropped it. With source code editor you are just editing plain text, with word processor you need advanced styling and formatting and contentEditable just does not cut that.

Comment: The fact that there are not yet good word processors based on HTML is the answer to the question.

Comment: modern source-code editors are editing plain text, true - but they do not simply use `<textarea>` which would not allow for syntax-highlighting - see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example, it simulates a cursor and uses `<span>` tags for rendering. You could use the same approach to create a word-processor that does not rely on contentEditable, which, I agree, does not cut it. Perhaps Mozilla took the wrong approach? Maybe if they had started with a proper scene-graph like [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) they would have had more luck...

Comment: I have to correct myself - jsfiddle does not use a simulated cursor, it actually does use contentEditable. [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html) is another editor with syntax-highlighting, which does use a simulated cursor and demonstrates the approach I'm suggesting. Carefully rightclick on the cursor in the editor-window and inspect with FireBug or Chrome, you will see the cursor is actually a DOM element.

Comment: I beg to differ: In my experience, Google Docs IS a good word processor. That proves that there is at least ONE good word processor written in javascript. Now, you can ask the question of weather you can do better than Google Docs but the question of weather it can be done at all is answered by the existance of Google Docs.

Comment: Please check Syncfusion [Document Editor](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/document-editor). It uses a custom canvas based render engine for proper WYSIWYG editing experience.

Answer (score 0):

ConstEdit at http://www.constedit.com may be such a word processor that satisfies your requirements on html5/css3, but not javascript.

It generates documents in the html format. Html5 sectioning elements tags are fully supported. There is an option to generate css stylesheets. It is not web-based. It runs locally on your pc.

You may give it a try. It is free for non-commercial users.

(Please note that I am the author of this software)

Comment: Please be aware that [you must disclose your affiliation with the product](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) if recommending products you are associated with. Please edit this answer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am *very* interested in this issue, too.  I want to be able to take templates and finalize my cover letters and similar format-critical documents via an online word processor.
I detest CKeditor and the other html editors.  They are definitely not WYSIWYG.

The best one I've found so far is www.TeamLab.com       I have no affiliation with them at all.  I think they already recognize the monetary value of their online word processor.  They are not giving out their API's and last time I spoke with them they said they will not do so for a number of months - presumably to assess how they want to charge for this valuable WP feature.

I am an attorney who needs to have proper looking letters and documents.  I have my own online application, and the online word-processing feature is only one small - but very important - aspect that I want to add to my app for my staff attorneys to have. 
I may be wrong but ConstEdit seemed to be just preliminary.  If I am wrong, I would very much like to talk to you.  I can give you good advice from a User's perspective.

Another group that I think is working on this concept is www.TheFormTool.com   They indicated they have a secret project, and I suspect it is this very html5 word processor.

As a user it is my opinion that such a product would be very valuable.  I encourage people to pursue this.

Answer (score -1):

Only reliable way to find out is to attempt it yourself, and see if you're blocked by something missing in the tech stack you're using (in this case js/html5/css).